# Insert output of curl command to a line number in a file

Tags: linux, bash, script, sed, curl

Working on a script to automate a few things. Been having and issue with running a sed command to inser the output of curl to a line number in a file

I have tried multiple variations of the command and i get nothing but errors from sed.

```
sed "49i/.*/\"$(curl URL)\"/" file.php
sed: -e expression #1, char 105: extra characters after command
```

Any ideas appericated
Thanks

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `curl URL` (after `$()` removes *trailing* newline(s)) probably contains newline character(s). It gets inserted in the command line argument that is supposed to be your script for `sed`. The tool parses the code, encounters a newline after `49i` and interprets what follows as the next command in the script.

You got an error. It could be worse: the output from `curl` could inject syntactically valid `sed` code into the script. You don't want this.

Even if you use `$(curl URL | tr -d '\n')` to remove *all* newlines, the output of `curl` may still not be inserted verbatim (e.g. backslashes will have special meaning).

Solution: let `curl` write to a temporary file, then let `sed` print the file. The content of the file will not be interpreted as code.

It seems you want the output from `curl` to appear before the original content of the 49th line. If so, you need to use `r` on the 48th line (because `r` schedules text for later output).

Your code tries to insert something in a form `/.*/"curl output here"/`. If this is not an artifact from trying to use the syntax of `s` with `i`, then you should write these additional fragments to the file as well.

Normally you can make `curl` write to a file by using `curl -o`. In this case it may not be what you want because it doesn't remove trailing newlines (while `$()` you used does). So *maybe* this:

```
tmpfile="$(mktemp)"
printf '/.*/"%s"/' "$(curl URL)" >"$tmpfile"
sed "48 r $tmpfile" file.php
rm "$tmpfile"
```

Note in general it will fail if the output from `curl` is too long. A more robust solution is to make `curl` print to the file directly and to [remove the newline(s) from the end](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254644/108618) in the next step.

The path to the temporary file must not contain newlines. If it does contain newlines then some part(s) of the path will be interpreted as sed command(s), possibly invalid; a bug somewhat similar to what you experienced. The path won't contain newlines, unless your `$TMPDIR` contains them (but it really shouldn't). In case of problems (e.g. `mktemp` is unavailable) use another method of picking a temporary location. In the most basic setup the location may be hardcoded (but then you shouldn't run more than one instance of the script simultaneously).

Comment: While using `r` is probably a nicer approach to my suggestion of sticking with `i`, I'm not sure your proposed solution works "_properly_" - it inserts the literal text that is found in `${tmpfile}`, which I don't think is OP's desired behaviour - I had expected that swapping the `printf ...` for just `curl ${url} > ${tmpfile}` would be what they're after...?

Comment: @Attie I admit it's not clear what they are after. `printf …` is there because `curl … > …` (or `curl -o …`) would write trailing newlines (if any) to the file. In the original code `$()` strips them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution works really well. Just need to add a newline at the start and end of the insert for formatting.

Comment: @Attie Thanks, printf remove the newline from the start and end of the line, curl piped to ${tmpfile} is doing excatly what i need it to do. Much appericated

Answer (score 1):

`sed`'s `i...\n` command doesn't have the same syntax as `s/.../.../...`, which I think is the main issue here. Along with the fact that your `curl` output likely contains newlines, which end up terminating the `i` command.

---

`s/find/replace/` will search for `find` and swap it for `replace`

In the example below, the text that matches the regex `3` is swapped out.

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed 's/3/new line/'
1
2
new line
4
5
```

---

`inew line` will insert `new line` before the matched line(s)

In the example below, we've not given an address or match, so *every* input line has `new line` inserted before it.

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed 'inew line'
new line
1
new line
2
new line
3
new line
4
new line
5
```

What you're trying to do appears to be insert the new line at a given line number (aka "*address*"), which can be achieved like this. Note that the `i` command is terminated by a newline (or end of string) - the `new line` is inserted before, it does not replace line three.

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed '3inew line'
1
2
new line
3
4
5
```

---

Now, as you're using the output of `curl`, you may well find that this contains a newline in it, which would terminate the `i` command... so you'll need to convert `curl`'s output into a single line, or only include the first line - you can use tools like `head` or `xxd` to help:

```
$ curl "${url}"
line one
line two
line three
```

Only keep first line:

```
$ new_line="$(curl -s "${url}" | head -n 1)"
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed '3i'"${new_line}"
1
2
line one
3
4
5
```

Escape all line breaks (`\r\n` and `\n`) into the literal characters `\n`. `sed` will then convert these back into a line break:

```
$ new_line="$(curl -s "${url}" | xxd -p | sed -re 's/(0d)?0a/5c6e/g;s/5c6e$//' | xxd -r -p)"
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed '3i'"${new_line}"
1
2
line one
line two
line three
3
4
5
```

Escape all line breaks (`\r\n` and `\n`) into the literal characters `\\n`. `sed` will then convert these into a the literal characters `\n`, resulting in a single line being inserted:

```
$ new_line="$(curl -s "${url}" | xxd -p | sed -re 's/(0d)?0a/5c5c6e/g;s/5c5c6e$//' | xxd -r -p)"
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed '3i'"${new_line}"
1
2
line one\nline two\nline three
3
4
5
```

---

This demonstrates that it *is possible*, however a better approach may be to just reconstruct the file using `head`, `curl` and `tail`, like this... it'll probably be more readable in the future:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" > "${file}"
$ tmpfile="$(mktemp)"
$ ( head -n 2 < "${file}"; curl "${url}"; tail -n +3 < "${file}" ) > "${tmpfile}"
$ mv "${tmpfile}" "${file}"
$ cat "${file}"
1
2
line one
line two
line three
3
4
5
```

Comment: At the moment, the script will remove the block of text that is current at the line number so that line is currently blank, the output from curl is 8 lines containing api keys.So i just need to insert the output to the empty line. I will try your suggestion when i get a moment to do so